# Print Each Pass of Sorted List

Tags: python

I am trying to print each pass of a bubble sort, along with the count of the change.
Ex:

1 [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8]

2 [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8]

3 [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8] and so on.

Here is my code so far:

```
def main():
    lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    bubbleSort(lst)


def bubbleSort(inputList):
    didSwap = True

    while didSwap:
        didSwap = False

        for i in range(len(inputList) - 1):

            if inputList[i] > inputList[i + 1]:
                inputList[i], inputList[i + 1] = inputList[i + 1], 
                     inputList[i]
                didSwap = True
                print(inputList)


main()
```

`
This is my output for this code:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 9, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Clearly, it sorts the list properly and prints each pass. However, it does not print the count at each change at the beginning of each pass. What am I missing?

Comment: Well if you don't tell it to print that number, why should it? "What am I missing?" Answer: a counter to count the changes, and add it to the `print` statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Tyler, if you are looking to print `i` you can do the following: `print(i, inputList)` instead of just `print(inputList)`.

Comment: @colelemonz `i` is not what needs to be printed.

Comment: @Tyler what do you need to print?

Comment: @colelemonz I need to simply number my lines of output. The output that I have is good, just needs number indicating which pass of the sort it is on. 1 for first line, 2 for second line of output and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a variable count and increase it on each itteration

```
def bubblesort(InputList):
    didswap = True
    count = 0

    while didswap:
        didswap = False
        count += 1

        ...

        print(count, InputList)
```